# cannot find symbol Image_picker

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Launching lib/intro.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
/Users/admin/Documents/FlutterApp/zarulem_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
import io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin;
^
symbol: class ImagePickerPlugin
location: package io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker
/Users/admin/Documents/FlutterApp/zarulem_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin;
^
symbol: class LocationPlugin
location: package com.lyokone.location
/Users/admin/Documents/FlutterApp/zarulem_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin"));
^
symbol: variable ImagePickerPlugin
location: class GeneratedPluginRegistrant
/Users/admin/Documents/FlutterApp/zarulem_app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
LocationPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin"));
^
symbol: variable LocationPlugin
location: class GeneratedPluginRegistrant
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.6.4-pre.14, on Mac OS X 10.14.1 18B75, locale ru-KZ)
• Flutter version 1.6.4-pre.14 at /Users/admin/Documents/FlutterApp/flutter
• Framework revision 81c38b2 (7 days ago), 2019-05-24 22:51:02 -0400
• Engine revision 8dc3a4cde2
• Dart version 2.3.2 (build 2.3.2-dev.0.0 e3edfd36b2)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
• CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
• ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 31.1.1
• Dart plugin version 181.5656
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
• Almaz • 042cc67b0b4f1661533c9c912c31df1ece93d66e • ios • iOS 12.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Automatically:

(For Android Studio)

1. Open the android project. (the 'android' folder under the Flutter project)
2. Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX